# Adding database to Mezzanine project produces "sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: django_site"

Tags: python, django, mezzanine, django-database

I'm trying to add a third-party database to a Mezzanine 4.2.3 project (it uses Django 1.10.8 according to `requirements.txt`). It's to be used by an app called `food_crud`. However, it produces this error: `sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: django_site`.

Most solutions I've read say to `makemigrations` and `migrate`. A few say to add `django.contrib.sites` to `INSTALLED_APPS`. I've tried both.

Project directory layout:

```
180214 food
- env_food # virtualenv
- food
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    router.py
    urls.py
    views.py
    wsgi.py
- food_crud
    - migrations
    __init__.py
    admin.py
    models.py
    tests.py
    views.py
- static
    ...
- theme
    ...
__init__.py
manage.py
movie_data.sql
```

The `food_crud` app is in `INSTALLED_APPS`. `settings.py` also contains the database details:

```
DATABASES = {
"default": {
    "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2",
    "NAME": "db_nate",
    "USER": "alex",
    "PASSWORD": "oh no you did not use password did you",
    "HOST": "localhost",
    "PORT": "",
},
"movies": {
    "ENGINE": "django.db.backends.sqlite3",
    "NAME": "movie_data.sql",
}
}

DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['food.router.FoodRouter']
```

Here's `router.py`, in the same folder as `settings.py`:

```
from food_crud import models

class FoodRouter(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        model = models.Movies

        if model._meta.app_label == 'food_crud':
            return 'movies'

        return None
```

`models.py`:

```
from django.db import models

class Movies(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    adult = models.TextField()
    original_language = models.TextField()
    original_title = models.TextField()
    title = models.TextField()
    overview = models.TextField()
    release_date = models.DateField()
    genres = models.TextField()
    production_countries = models.TextField()
    videos = models.TextField()
    images = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        app_label = "food_crud"
        db_table = "movies"
        managed = False
```

`views.py`:

```
from django.views import generic
from .models import Movies

class MoviesListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Movies
    template_name = r'"/food/theme/templates/food_crud/food_crud.html"'
```

`urls.py`:

```
...
from . import views
from food_crud import views as food_crud_views

urlpatterns += [
    url("^$", views.blog_post_list_index, name="home"),
    url('food/', food_crud_views.MoviesListView.as_view(), name='food_list'),
...
```

Traceback:

```
  File "C:\Users\alex\Desktop\Python\180214~1\food\env_food\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 42, in inner
response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\alex\Desktop\Python\180214~1\food\env_food\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 249, in _legacy_get_response
response = self._get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\alex\Desktop\Python\180214~1\food\env_food\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 178, in _get_response
response = middleware_method(request, callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\alex\Desktop\Python\180214~1\food\env_food\lib\site-packages\mezzanine\pages\middleware.py", line 75, in process_view
for_user=request.user, include_login_required=True)
  File "C:\Users\alex\Desktop\Python\180214~1\food\env_food\lib\site-packages\mezzanine\pages\managers.py", line 68, in with_ascendants_for_slug
pages_for_user = self.published(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\alex\Desktop\Python\180214~1\food\env_food\lib\site-packages\mezzanine\pages\managers.py", line 24, in published
published = super(PageManager, self).published(for_user=for_user)
  File "C:\Users\alex\Desktop\Python\180214~1\food\env_food\lib\site-packages\mezzanine\core\managers.py", line 70, in published
Q(status=CONTENT_STATUS_PUBLISHED))
  File "C:\Users\alex\Desktop\Python\180214~1\food\env_food\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\alex\Desktop\Python\180214~1\food\env_food\lib\site-packages\mezzanine\core\managers.py", line 378, in get_queryset
lookup = {self.__field_name + "__id__exact": current_site_id()}
  File "C:\Users\alex\Desktop\Python\180214~1\food\env_food\lib\site-packages\mezzanine\utils\sites.py", line 56, in current_site_id
site = Site.objects.get(domain__iexact=domain)
  File "C:\Users\alex\Desktop\Python\180214~1\food\env_food\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\alex\Desktop\Python\180214~1\food\env_food\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 379, in get
num = len(clone)
  File "C:\Users\alex\Desktop\Python\180214~1\food\env_food\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 238, in __len__
self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\alex\Desktop\Python\180214~1\food\env_food\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1087, in _fetch_all
self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
  File "C:\Users\alex\Desktop\Python\180214~1\food\env_food\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 54, in __iter__
results = compiler.execute_sql()
  File "C:\Users\alex\Desktop\Python\180214~1\food\env_food\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 835, in execute_sql
cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\alex\Desktop\Python\180214~1\food\env_food\lib\site-packages\debug_toolbar\panels\sql\tracking.py", line 164, in execute
return self._record(self.cursor.execute, sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\alex\Desktop\Python\180214~1\food\env_food\lib\site-packages\debug_toolbar\panels\sql\tracking.py", line 106, in _record
return method(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\alex\Desktop\Python\180214~1\food\env_food\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 79, in execute
return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\alex\Desktop\Python\180214~1\food\env_food\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\alex\Desktop\Python\180214~1\food\env_food\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\alex\Desktop\Python\180214~1\food\env_food\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py", line 685, in reraise
raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\alex\Desktop\Python\180214~1\food\env_food\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 64, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\alex\Desktop\Python\180214~1\food\env_food\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 337, in execute
return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: django_site
```

This same project directory layout and its various settings, including for the databases, work well with a Django 2.0 project. I duplicated them in this Mezzanine project but with names edited to fit it. What have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your router hard codes the model to Movies, which not surprisingly means it always matches the food_crud app.  So all db requests are being routed to your sqlite db.

Don't do that; remove that overriding of the `model` variable.

Comment: The overriding model was there because otherwise the Django 2.0 project I mentioned would throw a positional error, for some reason. But I just removed it from both projects and they work equally well now. Thank you so much!